# React Native disable console.warn yellow box from the app screen bottom

Tags: android, reactjs, console, react-native

I want to remove `console.warn` and all other warning messages that happen to appear on my react native app with a single line of code. Before I have achieved this by adding the following in my **App.js**

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

But somehow it is not working now, the code still exists in my **App.js** but the warning on yellow box is still showing on the bottom of the screen. Since my app is large which uses several packages and I have also added `console.warn` in many places, I need a solution to disable this from a single place

Someone please kelp me to identify why `console.disableYellowBox = true;` is not working or please provide some alternate solution to fix this .

> My react native version is 0.60.5

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this it will remove the obvious warnings.

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader', 'RNDeviceInfo', 'Warning: An update']);
```

Comment: Does it remove all custom added `console.warn` also ?   Also where to add the above code? I have import as follows `import {YellowBox} from 'react-native;` in my  `App.js` file

Comment: Yes it will remove all custom added warning. You need to add this code in your App.js file. And yes you can import it from "react-native"

Comment: But still that yello box appears ,I have tested with `console.warn("test warning");`

Comment: Have you added this warning in ignoreWarnings Array?

Comment: Yes it does remove the warning when I add `ignoreWarnings(['test warning']);'  But I need a general solution like `console.disableYellowBox = true;` for all warning. As I mentioned in the question It does work before but not now. Is there anything new for RN later versions? Anyway your answer is helpful if I need to remove a custom message

Comment: Yes, i understand your concern. 
Even i have also used console.disableYellowBox = true in earlier projects but it ain't working for now so we need to used this method and we were able to remove most frequent and annoying warnings for the time being.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206063/discussion-between-ajith-and-ajeett).

Answer (score 5):

For React-naitve 0.63

```
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()
```

and earlier version

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader', 'RNDeviceInfo', 'Warning: An update']);
```